# C# WinUI NavigationView MenuItemTemplate Throwing InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, winui

I'm trying to set up a NavigationView to be rendered by a list in the page's class, but I keep getting an exception thrown.

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'WinRT.IInspectable' to type 'FeatureBranching.Views.MenuItem'.'
```

I have the following code in XAML:

```xml
<Page ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewMenuItem" x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
            <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    ...

    <NavigationView Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="MainNavigation"
                    Header="This is Header Text"
                    PaneDisplayMode="Left"
                    IsSettingsVisible="False"
                    MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind NavigationMenuItems}"
                    MenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewMenuItem}"
                    SelectionChanged="MainNavigation_SelectionChanged">
    </NavigationView>
</Page>
```

Code behind class has:

```cs
public IEnumerable<MenuItem> NavigationMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>()
{
    new MenuItem
    {
        Name = "Repositories",
        Children= new List<MenuItem>()
        {
            new MenuItem
            {
                Tag = "123",
                Name = "Test123",
                Children = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>()
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It must have something to do with the DataTemplate because if I remove the `DataType` and `x:Bind` pieces from the DataTemplate and put constant strings in then it renders without exception. I've also tried making the list an `ObservableCollection` and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why (still new to WinUI development) but changing the `{x:Bind...}` inside the data template to `{Binding...}` fixed it. The Microsoft documentation uses `x:Bind` though, so not sure what that is about. If anyone knows why that would be great to know!

My DataTemplate is now... `<NavigationViewItem Content="{Binding Path=Name}" MenuItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" />`

Comment: For my own information can you provide the definition of your MenuItem class?  Thx.

Comment: I have the same issue, very strange that Microsoft documentation doesn't work :-(